# Determine the $C^\infty$ function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ satisfying $f(x)f(y)= \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) dt,$ for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Q. Suppose that $f \not \equiv 0$ is an inifinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $$f(x)f(y)= \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) dt,$$ for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$,
Find the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{f(t)}{e^{t/3}}$ whenever $f(1)=45$ and $f''(1)=5$.

I got $f(0)=0$ and tried with $f(x)=\frac{2}{45} \frac{F(x+1)-F(x-1)}{2}$, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. But, How to connect this finite difference with $f''(1)$?

Or

Any thing can be done with $f(x)^2=\int_0^{2x} f(t)dt$ which essentially gives $f(x)f'(x)=f(2x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Differentiation w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ gives  $f'(x)f(y)=f(x+y)-f(x-y)$ and $f(x)f'(y)=f(x+y)+f(x-y)$. So $f'(x)f(y)+f(x)f'(y)=2f(x+y)$. The right hand side has the same derivetive w.r.t. $x$ and $y$. So  $f''(x)f(y)+f'(x)f'(y)=f'(x)f'(y)+f(x)f''(y)$. This gives $\frac {f''(x)} {f(x)}=\frac {f''(y)} {f(y)}$ which makes $\frac {f''(x)} {f(x)}$ a constant $a$. Now you can find $f$ explicitly using the conditions $f(1)=45$ and $f''(1)=5$.